# How to call Matlab-function from Matlab with a string as input

Tags: python, matlab

I want to run a self-written Matlab function, `my_function(string1,string2)`, from Python, and I tried using this command:
`!matlab -nosplash -r my_function(string1,string2)`

This works when I give two specific strings as input variables:
`!matlab -nosplash -r my_function('myfirststring','mysecondstring')`,
but it does not work when I give two variables that are strings:

```
string1='myfirststring'
string2='mysecondstring'
!matlab -nosplash -r my_function(string1,string2)
```

Matlab gives an error message:

```
Undefined function or variable 'string1'.
```

How can I give the actual string to the Matlab-function instead of the variable names?

Comment: You could save the variables in a text file which you then read from matlab.

Comment: Wow, is this really the most elegant solution? It will probably work though.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in python, but what you want is to force the evaluation of `string1` And not parse it to the MATLAB function. My guess is that if you put `eval(“”)` around `string1` and `string2` it will force the evaluation.

Comment: The line `!matlab -nosplash -r my_function(string1,string2)` does not work in Python. The `!` does work in MATLAB, though. So are you trying to call a MATLAB function from within MATLAB by spawning a new MATLAB instance? From MATLAB just do `my_function(string1,string2)`. Where is the Python code?

Comment: No this is not the most elegant solution, but a working solution. The most elegant solution would be https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html

Comment: I believe your problem is that no variable transferred, not even names. Thats when Matlab would say "Undefined function or variable 'string1'. " Try using a different variable name in Matlab to check that.